# .net core 2 REST API avoid stalled time (mainly at chrome)

Tags: rest, google-chrome, asp.net-core-webapi

I have simple api controller. When I call the action "Get()" serveral times form chrome the browser wait to finish previous call, to start next call (Stalled). In firefox I have 6 parallel connection and it works, but in chrome is only one. Why?
How I can implement api method to avoid stalled time? It is possible? When I have rest web api I want to send request to 15 actions in the same time from one browser. [image]

```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue/2; i++)
            {

            }
            return new string[] { "finished" };
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making the action async

Comment: yes, the result was the same